# Iterating through a list to analyze elements up to a position and start iterating at next position

Tags: python

I have a list of utterances and a sliding window with which to use to analyze utterances up to a certain point (window_size).  I want to be able to utilize that window size as the maximum limit for iterating through list elements and perform some task on a batch of elements up to the last element in the window size, and then start to iterate at the next position, using subsequent element batches that reflect the window size :

```
# Define the size of the sliding window
window_size = 3

# Define the conversation as a list of utterances
conversation = [
    "phrase1",
    "phrase2",
    "phrase3",
    "phrase4",
    "phrase5",
    "phrase6",
    "phrase7",
    "phrase8"

]
```

I am using this (modified) for loop but my desired outcome is not working:

```
for i in range(0,len(conversation),3):
    
    if i < window_size:
        window = conversation[:i+3]
    else:
        window = conversation[i::2]
    print (window)
```

What I had intended would happen would be something like this (viewing the print statement as debug below as it goes through the for loop:

```
['phrase1', 'phrase2', 'phrase3']
['phrase3', 'phrase4', 'phrase5']
['phrase5', 'phrase6', 'phrase7']
['phrase7', 'phrase8']
['phrase8]
```

What is being returned in this methodology is:

```
['phrase1', 'phrase2', 'phrase3']
['phrase4', 'phrase6', 'phrase8']
['phrase7']
```

Any thoughts on how I could achieve this would be greatly appreciated.  I've tried a couple of different loop methodologies but not seem to get me this outcome.

Comment: That's not a sliding window.  That's just subdividing the list.  Do `for i in range(0,len(conversation),3):`.

Comment: You say *"Define the window based on the current utterance"* but then completely ignore the current utterance and make a decision based in `i` instead. How does that make sense?

Comment: @TimRoberts I made some updates on the code based on your recommendations (and Kelly's formatting suggestions) but I am still coming up with the undesired output.  Thoughts?

Comment: OK, so it is a sliding window.  I retract my comment.  You need `for i in range(0,len(conversation),2):` and use `conversation[i:i+3]`.  Python will handle the partial set at the end.

Comment: @TimRoberts that mostly worked until the third loop, and then it seemed to not advance to the next loop sequence:

`for i in range(0,len(conversation),2):
    # Define the window based on the current utterance
    if i < window_size:
        window = conversation[i:i+3]`

results were:

`['phrase1', 'phrase2', 'phrase3']
['phrase3', 'phrase4', 'phrase5']
['phrase3', 'phrase4', 'phrase5']
['phrase3', 'phrase4', 'phrase5']`

Comment: No, that can't be.  Perhaps you should modify your question or ask another.

Comment: @TimRoberts I don't understand "No that can't be", because it is indeed what is happening (pasted output above).  Can you please provide your output if you actually ran the code based on my question?

Answer (score -1):

This was the right approach to achieve the desired outcome:

```
# code 

for i in range(0, len(conversation), 2):
    window = conversation[i:i+window_size]
    if i+window_size < len(conversation):
        window[2] = conversation[i+window_size-1]
    print(window)

# output
['phrase1', 'phrase2', 'phrase3']
['phrase3', 'phrase4', 'phrase5']
['phrase5', 'phrase6', 'phrase7']
['phrase7', 'phrase8']
['phrase8]
```